# Outlook 2013 VBA Editor Launches Without Displaying Debug and Edit Toolbars

Tags: windows-7, vba, microsoft-outlook-2013

Just an annoyance, but I've hunted through every editor command option to no avail. Just switched laptops, and in my old VBA editor it launched each time with no code windows open and the debug and edit toolbar docked at the top of the screen as I prefer.

Now no matter what I do when I launch the Outlook VBA editor I have to reopen and dock the debug and edit tool bars and close all the code windows that are open in a hodgepodge fashion on the screen.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Are you using the same version of Outlook? Or did you change when you switched laptops?

Comment: I know my VBE for excel looks very different on OSX than Windows, so the question @CharlieRB has asked may be key.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, went from Outlook 2013 to Outlook 2013.  Both machines are Win 7.

Answer (score 0):

According to [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233702/where-does-outlook-store-the-vba-code-files), personal macros are stored in a single file named in the user's `%appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook folder`, which will be a hidden folder on most systems.  I suggest making the changes there, and also dock the toolbars via View>Toolbars.  This worked for me.